# Continuity on a metric space: equivalent formulations

Tags: real-analysis

I am using Elementary Classical Analysis by Marsden and Hoffman.
One of the theorems is the following:
Let $f : M \rightarrow N$ where $M,N$ are metric spaces and $A \subset M$.
Then the following statements are equivalent.

1) $f$ is continuous on $A$.
2) If $U \subset N$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U) \subset A$ is open relative to A.

My question regards the stipulation that $f^{-1}(U) \subset A$. Is this a conclusion, or a condition, of the theorem? It obviously seems like a condition, since there seems to be no reason for an arbitrary open set $U$ to have a preimage contained in $A$, but I want to confirm this for clarity.

Comment: You sure it's $\subset$ and not $\cap$?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, then. Consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto x^2$. Then $f$ is continuous everywhere, so it's continuous on $A:=[1,4]$. But, if we let $U$ be $(1,4)$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is $(-2,-1)\cup(1,2)$, which is not a subset of $A$.

Comment: In fact, since $U$ is allowed to be _any_ open subset of $N$… this doesn't make any sense. $“f^{-1}(U)\color{Red}\cap A”$ makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

When the authors say open **relative** to $A$, I believe they mean that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open w.r.t. to $A$ as a metric subspace of $M$.

Comment: I know what "open relative to" means. I am asking whether the statement in the theorem $f^{-1}(U) \subset A$ is a condition or conclusion of the theorem.